# Count number of related Cases To a Contact

Tags: trigger, field-update

I have created a trigger to count the number of Cases related to a Contact.
But my field does not update.
Could someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

```
trigger ContactRelatedCasesTrigger on Contact (before insert, before update) {

List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>([SELECT Id, (SELECT ContactId FROM Cases) FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New]);
System.debug('Contact Number ' +conList.size());

for(Contact con : conList) {
    con.Number_of_Cases__c = con.Cases.size();
    System.debug('Number Related Cases ' +con.Number_of_Cases__c);
}
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trigger only updates when a contact is edited. It'd be better to put the trigger on the case:

```
trigger UpdateCaseContactCount on Case (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    Map<Id, Contact> contactsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Contact>();
    if(Trigger.new != null) {
        for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
            contactsToUpdate.put(record.ContactId, new Contact(Id=record.ContactId,Case_Count__c=0));
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.old != null) {
        for(Case record: Trigger.old) {
            contactsToUpdate.put(record.ContactId, new Contact(Id=record.ContactId,Case_Count__c=0));
        }
    }
    contactsToUpdate.remove(null);
    for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT COUNT(Id) caseCount, ContactId ContactId FROM Case WHERE ContactId = :contactsToUpdate.keySet() GROUP BY ContactId]) {
        contactsToUpdate.get((Id)result.get('ContactId')).Case_Count__c=(Integer)result.get('caseCount');
    }
    update contactsToUpdate.values();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the *trigger context records*, not those you queried for. Put the query results in a `Map`, and then reference that map while looping over `trigger.new`.

```
Map<Id, Contact> caseCounts = new Map<Id, Contact>([/*same query*/]);
for (Contact record : trigger.new)
{
    record.Number_of_Cases__c = caseCounts.get(record.Id).Cases.size();
}
```

Note that if you put this logic only in the `Contact` trigger, your rollup will frequently be out of date, as all the trigger bindings where the data actualy changes would be on `Case`.